# Reading text file line by line character by character

Tags: c++, file-handling

I have a text file that has the following  format:

```
number1 number2   //line1
number3 number4   //line2
```

What statements would I use to read it line by line. I have used fgets but it stops once a newline character is encountered.. How do I make it to point to the beginning of the next line each time ? Also after storing each line in a buffer, I need to store them  number by number, from  each line.. What can I use for this as well?

Comment: Is the comment part of the file?

Comment: To read line-by-line, `fgets()` is fine - you just have to call it again to get the next line.

Comment: No the comment was just for illustrative purposes

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the standard C++ iostreams idiom:

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");

for (int a, b; infile >> a >> b; )
{
    // use a, b
}
```